# Detecting boundaries/edges - MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am generating random numbers using randi and then adding and subtracting a certain amount from the random number:

```
for k=1:1000
     dist = poissrnd(RsMean,1,1);
     points(k,1) = randi([1, 1000]); 
     edges(k,1) = points(k,1)-dist;
     edges(k,2) = points(k,1)+dist;
end
```

When the edges are calculated, I want it to take into consideration that the values can not go beyond the boundaries (in this case 1-1000). For example, currently, if points contains a value of 20, and dist = 450, the edge will record -430 and 470.

I know I could just do this:

```
edges(edges<1) = 1;
edges(edges>1000) = 1000;
```

But is there a more concise manner to do edge checks on MATLAB?

Comment: It's hard to make it more concise than those two lines. Assuming you meant `edges(edges<1) = 1;` in the first line, you could replace both lines by `edges = min(max(edges,1),1000)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is really more concise, but you can use min and max:

```
% Take the minimum between edges and 1000
edges = min(edges, 1000)
% Take the maximum between edges and 1
edges = max(edges, 1)
```